# не читаемый текст при запросе SQL (pymssql Python)

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Посылаю запросd Бд в ответе в строчках с кириллицей получаю кракозябры
52  E08359974  ÀÑÐÇ
53  E08359975  ÀÑÐÇ
54  E08359976  ÀÑÐÇ
сам код:

```
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
server = 'DBRCS01'
username = 'YEP'
password = 'gjhq1w2'
database = 'R1'
table_name = 'RSNGLt'
conn = pymssql.connect(host=server, user=username, password=password, database=database)
cursor = conn.cursor()
print('Посылаем запрос в БД')
cursor.execute("""select top 55 НомерИнцидента, Источник
                   from RSNGLt""")
results = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.close()
conn.close()
print(results)
```

Comment: У pymssql.connect есть параметр `charset`. Попробуйте явно указать `cp1251`

Comment: Я пробовал так: conn = pymssql.connect(host=server, user=username, password=password, database=database, charset="cp1252"), ничего не меняется, а если заменить на charset="cp1251" то выдает ошибку UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 12-15: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0):

Пока не нашел ничего лучше чем кодировать каждый столбец:

```
results[12] = [x.encode("windows-1252").decode("windows-1251") for x in results[12]]
```